# Eclipse CDT - stdout, stdin and stderr gone kaput

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've been working with Eclipse-CDT Helios 7.0.1 for few months now. Recently I downloaded Juno and tried install both MinGW and CygWin using their portable web-installers.

I've slow internet connection => multiple attempts to download MinGW and CygWin packages. I selected Dev packages in CygWin and stable packages in MinGW if my memory serves me correct.

Problem: 
1. Juno is not opening at all, it's throwing exceptions and exits.
2. Helios, although it compiles files console is not working.

Could someone point me out in right direction?

Comment: What exceptions is Juno throwing?

Comment: Sounds like a problem I had. I found an okay solution with setting the .gdbinit to `set new-console on` but I eventually gave up and used Visual Studio. I don't regret it one bit.